# Hadoop : sqoop : getting Unknown database 'sample' error even though database exist

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I'm doing basic try in `sqoop`. using MySQL i have created a database sample. I've created a table customers in 'sample' database, inserted some data into the table.

While trying to import the table to hdfs using sqoop I'm getting `Unknown database 'sample'`, even though database present.

sqoop command used:

```
sqoop import --connect "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample" --username root --password 123456 --table customers --target-dir hdfs:/sqoop/customers2  -m 1
```

but this command shows table customer:

```
sqoop list-tables --connect "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample" --username root --password 123456"
```

Since table & schema is accessible & works fine for list-tables command not sure why import command fails.

I tried following:

1. grant all privilege to customer table.
2. remove port number in --connect url.
3. tried IP instead of localhost (getting error as "The driver has not received any packets from the server" )

Please suggest what could be issue.

would be thankful for your response.

Log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'sample'
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.setConf(DBInputFormat.java:167)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:62)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:722)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'sample'
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
```

Comment: Is it a distributed Hadoop cluster? Also, login into MySQL and check whether it's running and the database `sample` exists.

Comment: visakh - its sudo distributed. yes sample database exist.

Comment: mysql is running as well.

Comment: Did you solve this problem later? I had this problem just now, spending 30 minutes to find out it's just because of a typo in the database name.... '_' and '-' is too close...

Answer (score 0):

Try this , it will work

sqoop import  --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost.localdomain/DVS_DB   --username hadoop  --password hadoop  --table DEPT --target-dir sqoop_dir/ --m 1;