# SCOOP ERROR of database name does not exists even though it exists

Tags: mysql, sqoop, hadoop2

I have 3 nodes , one namenode1, datanode1 and datanode2. 
Scoop and mysql are installed on namenode1.

when can c the list of database as test.

```
hadoop@namenode1:/usr/local/sqoop/lib$ sqoop list-databases --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/ --username root --password hadoop
18/08/25 19:49:58 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.7
18/08/25 19:49:58 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
18/08/25 19:49:58 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
information_schema
metastore
mysql
performance_schema
test
```

but when i run 
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test --username root --password hadoop --table student;

```
hadoop@namenode1:/usr/local/sqoop/lib$ sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test --username root --password hadoop --table student;
18/08/25 19:43:37 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.7
18/08/25 19:43:37 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
18/08/25 19:43:37 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
18/08/25 19:43:37 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
18/08/25 19:43:38 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `student` AS t LIMIT 1
18/08/25 19:43:38 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `student` AS t LIMIT 1
18/08/25 19:43:38 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /usr/local/hadoop
Note: /tmp/sqoop-hadoop/compile/2a56cd695f49348fad38af086755acd8/student.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
18/08/25 19:43:41 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-hadoop/compile/2a56cd695f49348fad38af086755acd8/student.jar
18/08/25 19:43:41 WARN manager.MySQLManager: It looks like you are importing from mysql.
18/08/25 19:43:42 WARN manager.MySQLManager: This transfer can be faster! Use the --direct
18/08/25 19:43:42 WARN manager.MySQLManager: option to exercise a MySQL-specific fast path.
18/08/25 19:43:42 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Setting zero DATETIME behavior to convertToNull (mysql)
18/08/25 19:43:42 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning import of student
18/08/25 19:43:42 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
18/08/25 19:43:43 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
18/08/25 19:43:43 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at namenode1/192.168.1.2:8050
18/08/25 19:43:46 INFO db.DBInputFormat: Using read commited transaction isolation
18/08/25 19:43:46 INFO db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat: BoundingValsQuery: SELECT MIN(`id`), MAX(`id`) FROM `student`
18/08/25 19:43:46 INFO db.IntegerSplitter: Split size: 0; Num splits: 4 from: 1 to: 2
18/08/25 19:43:46 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
18/08/25 19:43:47 INFO Configuration.deprecation: yarn.resourcemanager.system-metrics-publisher.enabled is deprecated. Instead, use yarn.system-metrics-publisher.enabled
18/08/25 19:43:47 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1535200795373_0015
18/08/25 19:43:48 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1535200795373_0015
18/08/25 19:43:48 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://namenode1:8088/proxy/application_1535200795373_0015/
18/08/25 19:43:48 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1535200795373_0015
18/08/25 19:43:57 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1535200795373_0015 running in uber mode : false
18/08/25 19:43:57 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
18/08/25 19:44:03 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1535200795373_0015_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
**Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'test'**
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.setDbConf(DBInputFormat.java:170)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.setConf(DBInputFormat.java:161)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:137)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:755)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:177)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1886)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:171)
**Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'test'**
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.getConnection(DBInputFormat.java:223)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.setDbConf(DBInputFormat.java:168)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'test'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4237)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4169)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:928)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1750)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1290)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2493)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2311)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
```

I have given grant

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'127.0.0.1';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

but i am not sure why this error is coming . when database is present.

Comment: have you refered to this thread <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24283583/hadoop-sqoop-getting-unknown-database-sample-error-even-though-database-ex?rq=1>

Comment: problem something else, when we run the mysql command in distributed platform then sqoop expects mysql command should be interpreted on all nodes and thats the reason why we need to install it on all nodes. hope this explains the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MYSQL needs to be installed on all nodes

when we run the mysql command in distributed platform then sqoop expects mysql command should be interpreted on all nodes and thats the reason why we need to install it on all nodes. hope this explains the answer

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21160418)

Comment: when we run the mysql command in distributed platform then sqoop expects mysql command should be interpreted on all nodes and thats the reason why we need to install it on all nodes. hope this explains the answer